# What does it mean to “link against” something - etymologically?

Tags: libraries, terminology

I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23177550/what-does-it-mean-to-link-against-something) question on Stack Overflow. The answer is both thorough and correct, but I don't know why the word "against" is used when people talk about libraries. "Against" implies a conflict, but I would not include a library in my program that is actively counter to my goals. It seems to me that "link with" is more descriptive of my intentions than "link against".

Does anyone know why we use the phrase "link against" instead of "link with"?

Comment: One can _lean against_ a wall (or another) for support. It seems like a non-issue when dropping the notion of ‘against’ implying a conflict.

Comment: "Against" *always* implies a conflict, but I guess conflict can be constructive in the case of ladders for instance?

Comment: Here are three definitions from a dictionary: "In a direction or course opposite to.", "So as to come into forcible contact with.", "In contact with so as to rest or press on.". Each definition implies a force opposite to the one being applied. A ladder laying against a wall implies an equal and opposite force by the wall against the ladder.

Comment: And “in contact with” is ‘always’ an opposition?

Comment: Yes. Consider a baseball colliding with a wall. The baseball applies a force to the wall, and the wall applies an equal and opposite force to cause the baseball to stop. Also consider a book lying on a table. The book is applying a force equal to it's mass * 9.81 meters / second, but the table is applying an equal force to the book, so the book stays in place.

Comment: Despite the drive by down vote, I suggest you revert your question back to its original form, because it was actually original, and I can imagine someone finding it upon searching for technical usages and etymology of against.

Comment: Yeah, you're right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are lots of ways to suggest that one item is connected to or depends upon another.

A ladder leans *against* a building for support.  One tests an argument *against* various counters to ensure it is sound.

"Against"  is commonly used in mathematical or logical parlance in the latter way (but not the ladder way).  In these situations, while one element is against the other, they are not in conflict.

Answer (score 0):

[image: C++ compilation process diagram]

Just look at the last step 'linker'.

> The code I wrote(in the middle) "object code"

against

> The codes from other developers (Other object files)   and
> The libraries from other companies/orgs

Mean : "My code depends upon other codes/libraries".
Just like:

> a ladder leans against the wall.

---

"other codes/libraries" are **required** and **indispensable**.

"my codes" + "other codes/libraries" are used as **INPUT** data,
through linker,
and finally generate executable code as **OUTPUT**.

That is the point of 'against'.